# how to remove label from the clustericon in markerclusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am using markerclusterer.js to make cluster in a google map api. There are more than 500 markers in my map. So i am using cluster to show them properly. Everything is comming properly like the attached image
[image]

I am using this- https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer

But I want a little customization. I don't want to show the number of the markers over the icons. I want to remove those numbers. 
I tried

```
this.hideLabel_ = true;
```

in the markerclusterer connstrutor. but it didn't work properly. I t doesn't shows the number but take a space for the label. I am adding infowindow onhover of that clusterIcon. So Ineed to remove the label, not hiding(becoz it's still taking some space).

I am using 'mouseover' to open a infowindow and using 'mouseout' to close that infowindow. Now if I hover on the label the infowindow is blinking

Please I need help to sort this thing.

Comment: I am using 'mouseover' to open a infowindow and using 'mouseout' to close that infowindow. Now if I hover on the label the infowindow is blinking

Comment: @geocodezip I tried that answers.But my problem is if I hover on the cluster the infowindow is blinking becoz there may be no label(number is showing but it is not removed)

Comment: That is a different question than this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the calculator function - and just set the cluster label to empty string:

```
const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map,  options);

markerCluster.setCalculator(function (markers, numStyles) {
    var index = 0;
    var count = markers.length;
    var dv = count;
    while (dv !== 0) {
        dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
        index++;
    }

    index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
    return {
        text: "", // set to empty string
        index: index
    };
};
```

document suggests the styles object can set text size for the label.

> 'styles': (object) An object that has style properties:  *
>   'url': (string) The image url.  *       'height': (number) The image
>   height.  *       'width': (number) The image width.  *       'anchor':
>   (Array) The anchor position of the label text.  *       'textColor':
>   (string) The text color.  *       '**textSize**': (number) The text
>   size.  *       'backgroundPosition': (string) The position of the
>   backgound x, y.  *       'iconAnchor': (Array) The anchor position of
>   the icon x, y.

Comment: I tried this earlier. Using this there is no number showing over the icon but still take a space

Comment: It wasn't clear that this is what you wanted.  Have you tried setting the  style?  Docs sugest you can set the text size - maybe that will do it..

Comment: 'styles': (object) An object that has style properties:
 *       'url': (string) The image url.
 *       'height': (number) The image height.
 *       'width': (number) The image width.
 *       'anchor': (Array) The anchor position of the label text.
 *       'textColor': (string) The text color.
 *       'textSize': (number) The text size.
 *       'backgroundPosition': (string) The position of the backgound x, y.
 *       'iconAnchor': (Array) The anchor position of the icon x, y.